# What should be the value of b in the following code snippet and why? '-6' or '-7'

Tags: c

I want so see the values of the four variables (Basically checking the precedence order of logical operators).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=0, b=-7, c=0, d;
    d = ++c || ++a && ++b  ;
    printf("\n %d %d %d %d",a,b,c,d);
}
```

I expect the result to be '0 -6 1 1', but the actual output is '0 -7 1 1'. Can anyone please give an explanation behind the output shown?

Answer (score 2):

First have a look at [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Then, regarding the working of logical OR operator, from `C11`, chapter §6.5.14 (*emphasis mine*)

> [...] the `||` operator **guarantees left-to-right evaluation**; if the
>   second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first
>   and second operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is
>   not evaluated.**

and regarding the result:

> The `||` operator shall yield `1` if either of its operands compare unequal to `0`; otherwise, it
>   yields `0`. The result has type `int`.

So, in your code

```
 d = ++c || ++a && ++b  ;
```

is the same as

```
 d = (++c) || (++a && ++b);
```

which evaluates to

```
 d = 1 || (++a && ++b);         // short circuit, RHS not evaluated
```

which is finally same as

```
d = 1;  // 1 is not the value computation of `++c`, rather result of the `||` operation.
```

Comment: I agree is not `d = ++c;` but replacing `d = ++c || ++a && ++b  ;` by `d=1;` does not explain why _c_ becomes 1

Comment: @bruno What do you mean, I cannot understand you clearly

Comment: you are focused to explain why `(++a && ++b)` is not executed, and in a way 'forget' the modification of _c_, you do like if _c_ was initialized to 1 and not modified, the OP needed help and may be better to explain all, just my 2 cents ;-)